# Majority and its average in list of tuples

Tags: python

Suppose the following list of tuples representing sentiment estimates from 3 different methods:

```
[('pos', 0.2), ('neu', 0.1), ('pos', 0.4)]
```

I was wondering what is the most efficient way to find the majority sentiment, and for this to calculate its average, i.e.:

```
result=('pos', 0.3)
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you use NumPy or Pandas?

Comment: In what way do you want it to be efficient? Efficient use of CPU time, memory or developer time?

Comment: CPU time. The sentiments are fetched from thousands of API calls per second. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
import itertools

l = [('pos', 0.2), ('neu', 0.1), ('pos', 0.4)]
```

You can first group by the sentiment (note they need to be sorted first)

```
sentiments = [list(j[1]) for j in itertools.groupby(sorted(l), lambda i: i[0])]
# sentiments = [[('neu', 0.1)], [('pos', 0.2), ('pos', 0.4)]]
```

Then figure out which sentiment is most common (aka has the longest group)

```
majority = max(sentiments, key=len)
# majority = [('pos', 0.2), ('pos', 0.4)]
```

Then lastly compute the average

```
values = [i[1] for i in majority]
average = (majority[0][0], sum(values)/len(values))
# average = ('pos', 0.30000000000000004)
```

Comment: Using `l` as a variable name is a leading cause of cancer.

Comment: Thank you for this - I was wondering if a solution along the lines of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31212260/group-and-compute-the-average-in-list-of-tuples) would be an overkill for this case, but apparently it's not.

Answer (score 1):

using [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and the [`statistics`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html?highlight=statistics#module-statistics) module you could do this:

```
from collections import Counter
from statistics import mean

lst = [('pos', 0.2), ('neu', 0.1), ('pos', 0.4)]
count = Counter(item[0] for item in lst)  # Counter({'pos': 2, 'neu': 1})
maj = count.most_common(1)[0][0]          # pos
mn = mean(item[1] for item in lst if item[0] == maj)
result = (maj, mn)

print(result)  # ('pos', 0.30000000000000004)
```

although given you are looking for efficiency i prefer [CoryKramer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45101900/4954037).

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections

reports = [('pos', 0.2), ('neu', 0.1), ('pos', 0.4)]

oracle = collections.defaultdict(list)
for mood, score in reports:
    oracle[mood].append(score)

counts = {mood: len(scores) for mood, scores in oracle.items()}

mood = max(counts) # gives `'pos'`

sum(oracle[mood]) / len(oracle[mood]) # gives 0.3
```

Comment: Try changing `'neu'` to `'zeu'`. That breaks it.

Comment: Thanks - that's very comprehensive

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use Dictionary. Define a nested dictionary where 'key' is the sentiment name and value is a dictionary which contains : 'numbers'(key) which is the list of sentiment values(value) and 'count'(key) for the number of sentiment's occurrence(value). example:

```
sentiment['pos']['numbers'] = [0.2,0.4]
sentiment['pos']['count'] = 2
sentiment={'pos':{'numbers':[0.2,0.4],'count':2},'neu':{'numbers':`[0.1],'count:1'}}`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sorted_tuples = sorted(my_tuple_list, key = lambda x : x[-1] , reverse = True)

majority_sentiment=  sorted_tuples[0][0]
majority_sentiment_score = 0
num_items = 0

for sentiment_tup in sorted_tuples:
    if sentiment_tup[0] == majority_sentiment:
        majority_sentiment_score+= sentiment_tup[1]
        num_items +=1

avg_sentiment_score = majority_sentiment_score/num_items

result= (majority_sentiment,avg_sentiment_score)
```

That should do.

Comment: This finds just one item from the majority and it does not compute its average. Also `sorted(my_tuple_list, key = lambda x : x[-1] , reverse = True)[1]` returns the other 'pos' element